# Redirection to Application when link is clicked?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-8.1

How to add support to the application If click a link it should open the application for example I'm using Flipkart Application I shared a product Link to my friend if he clicks that link it will open the Application and the product which I shared I need this functionality for Windows Phone 8.1. If any help will be appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,
Harish Kinthali.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a custom URI to open your app, [explained here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779670.aspx).

So you could register `myappname://` to be handled by your app, then on a website (or in another app), if the user clicks a link starting with `myappname://`then it will launch your app.